# Index of closest points between two arrays

Tags: c++, stl

Given two vectors `foo` and `bar`, I want to output a vector of length `foo.size()` containing the index to the "closest" element of bar. I don't like reinventing the wheel - are there any STL algorithms or otherwise to do this concisely?

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <float.h>

int main() {
    vector<double> foo;
    vector<double> bar;

    // example data setup
    double array_foo[] = {0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0,
                          5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0};
    double array_bar[] = {4.8, 1.5, 12.0};
    foo.assign(array_foo, array_foo + 10);
    bar.assign(array_bar, array_bar + 3);

    // output array
    vector<int> indices;
    indices.resize(foo.size());

    for(int i = 0; i < foo.size(); i++) {
        double dist = DBL_MAX;
        int idx = 0;
        // find index of closest element in foo
        for(int j = 0; j < bar.size(); j++) {
            if(abs(foo[i] - bar[j]) < dist) {
                dist = abs(foo[i] - bar[j]);
                idx = j;
            }
        }
        indices[i] = idx;
    }
    // expected result: indices = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,2]
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exact algorithm doesn't exist, but you could implement it in an idiomatic STL way by using `std::min_element` and a custom functor:

```
template <typename T>
T norm(const T& a, const T& b)
{
    return abs(b - a);
}

template <typename T>
struct closer_compare
{
    closer_compare(const T& to) : to(to) {}
    bool operator()(const T& a, const T& b) const
    {
        return norm(a, to) < norm(b, to);
    }
    const T& to;
};

template <typename It1, typename It2, typename OutIt>
void find_nearest_indices(It1 in1_begin, It1 in1_end, It2 in2_begin, It2 in2_end, OutIt out)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It1>::value_type value;
    for (It1 it = in1_begin; it != in1_end; ++it)
    {
        It2 closest = std::min_element(in2_begin, in2_end, closer_compare<value>(*it));
        *out++ = std::distance(in2_begin, closest);
    }
}
```

Your algorithm would then be replaced with:

```
find_nearest_indices(foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar.begin(), bar.end(), indices.begin());
```

I tested with your input and got your expected results.

Answer (score 3):

I see 3 different solutions. They all offer the same complexity O(N * logN).

1.

Store elements if `bar` within the binary tree (`std::map`). Then for every element in `foo` you'll have to find up to two bounding elements, and select the best from them.

Building the tree is O(N * logN), second pass is O(N * logN)

2.

Same as above, except instead of using the binary tree you may use a sorted array. Create an array, each element of which consists of an element of `bar` and its index (alternatively your array should contain pointers to the elements of `bar`). Then, instead of the tree search you'll do the array search.

From the complexity point of view this is pretty the same. However practically search in the sorted array will probably be somewhat faster.

3.

Sort both `foo` and `bar`. (Yet again you'll have to either have an original index in your sorted array, or just store pointers to the original elements.

Now, for every element in sorted `foo` you don't have to do the full search in `bar`. Instead you should only check if you should remain at the current position at sorted `bar` or move forward.

Comment: Slight correction on the first option, building the `map` is also O(N*logN).

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the arrays are sorted, or if you're allowed to sort the arrays, you could use the STL `lower_bound` or `upper_bound` algorithms to do a binary search to locate a value from the second array in the first.  The returned iterator will point to the first element at least as large as (or strictly greater than in the case of `upper_bound`) your element, limiting the number of elements out of the first array you need to check to two.  This will run in O(m lg n), where m is the number of elements in the second array and n is the number in the first.

Comment: Your description of `lower_bound` is a little inaccurate - it returns the position of the first element `>=` the search term. I would use lower_bound exclusively; the nearest value will be either at that position or the one before it.

Comment: They're not sorted - sorry if this was implied by my choice of data.